# css href and links

Tags: html, css

It seems that when I add an 'href' tag to my anchor I lose all my css formatting.  Is there something special the way css treats links?

Here is the simple css

```
    .topmenu > ul > li > a:visited,
    .topmenu > ul > li > a:active,
    .topmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
    .topmenu > ul > li > a:link,
    .topmenu > ul > li > a { font-family:Arial; font-size:1.0em; font-weight:bold; color:White; text-decoration:none; }
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="topmenu">
    <label>Name of Dept.</label>
    <ul>                    
        <li><a href="http://www.myurl.com">Itinerary</a></li>
        <li><a>Team Members</a></li>
        <li>Fundraising</li>
        <li>Resources</li>
        <li>Dates</li>
    </ul>        
</div>
```

The  without the href formats properly.  The  with the href doesn't.  I would have thought that the css a:link and a:visited would have covered that scenario.  If I add !important to the css, then I get the proper formatting everywhere.

Comment: Just a note, in IE an anchor tag without an HREF is not recognized as a link.  Styling wise it does not get any of the css benefits of an anchor, such as hover, link, visited and active.

Comment: Ummm, you should try your minimal example. It works. At least in FF3 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can add !important to the rule is indicating you have another rule that is taking precedence. Do you have something that is targeting with a[href]?

Try loading up your page in Firebug or Safari's Developer tool and see if another style you have specified is overriding your rule.